# target a blackberry 5 using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, blackberry

I want to target all blackberry devices do some device specific changes. Following is the code I have written which obviously dosen't work. Thanks.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var isMobile = {
    BlackBerry: function() {
        var ua = "BlackBerry9000/5.0.0.93 Profile/MIDP-2.0 Configuration/CLDC-1.1 VendorID/179";
        return navigator.ua.match(/^BlackBerry[0-9]*/) ? true : false;
    },
    iOS: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone|iPad|iPod/i) ? true : false;
    },
    Windows: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/IEMobile/i) ? true : false;
    },
    any: function() {
        return (isMobile.Android() || isMobile.BlackBerry() || isMobile.iOS() || isMobile.Windows());
    }
};

if( isMobile.BlackBerry() ) {
    $('body').css('background','green');
    $('div.send-to-friend-form').css('display', 'block');
    $('a#add_body_hidden').hide();

}
```

EDIT: I got the answer and is working already. I will post it in few days when stackoverflow allows me to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a function that answers the questions and worked for me.

```
<!-- target the blackberry device -->
```

```
var isMobile = {
    BlackBerry: function() {
        var ua = navigator.userAgent;
        return (ua.indexOf("BlackBerry") >= 0) ? true : false;
    } // you can add more tests here for other phones
};

if( isMobile.BlackBerry() ) {
    $('div.send-to-friend-form').css('display', 'block');
    $('a#add_body_hidden').remove();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I generally frown upon useragent tests and prefer specific feature or capability detection because it's more accurate and longer lasting.

But, here's how RIM suggests you detect blackberry devices: http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Web-and-WebWorks-Development/How-to-detect-the-BlackBerry-Browser/ta-p/559862

Comment: @Subash - did check what?  Why doesn't RIM's suggested code work?

Comment: I am working on somebody elses left over project, which is quite messed up. There is javascript all over the site and the files are divided into small chunks as the site is integrated in CMS. Now I am not sure that why it didnt work, and finding that reason in the code is Nightmare for previously explained reason. But thanks a lot for help.